# Test class Account insert problem

Tags: unit-test

While calling save method from class into testclass its not covering.

```
    public class AccountContactController{

    public Account acc{get;set;}
    public List<Contact> cont{get;set;}

    public AccountContactController(){
        acc = new Account();
        cont = new List<Contact>();
        AddRow();
        AddRow();
        AddRow();

    }

    public void AddRow(){
        cont.add(new Contact());
   }

    public void save(){
        if(acc.name != null){
            insert acc;
            if(acc != null){
                List<contact> con = new List<contact>();
                for(Contact c : cont){
                    c.AccountId = acc.id;
                    con.add(c);
                }
                if(con != null){
                    insert con;
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

-----------------------------Test class ----------

```
 @isTest
private class AccountContactController_Test{

    static testMethod void unitTest(){

        AccountContactController Acc = new AccountContactController();
        Account ac = new Account();
        ac.name = 'test';
        insert ac;
        Acc.save();


    }

}
```

Comment: lastname is required field for a contact while inserting.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because, while you have included the relevant code, it doesn't really look like you've put any effort into your unit test. You've been around for a good amount of time, and have asked several questions on unit tests before this one, so I expect you to have learned more about unit testing than you've displayed here.

Comment: downvoted for same reasons as Derek F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialize the class using this line.

```
AccountContactController Acc = new AccountContactController();
```

The class variable `acc` is still not set.

The below lines are specific to the test class

```
Account ac = new Account();
ac.name = 'test';
insert ac;
```

So to satisfy the condition `if(acc.name != null)` inside save method. The `acc` object inside the controller should be set.

Like,

```
AccountContactController.acc.name = 'test';
```

This should pass the if condition `if(acc.name != null)`. Also you are inserting the `acc` Obj in `save` method, so its not required to insert in the test class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few changes in the `addRow()` function of your class first

```
public void AddRow(){

    cont.add(new Contact(lastName = 'Contact'));
    // you could also use this method as parameterized method to give contact a distinct name.
}
```

And in you test class

```
@isTest
private class AccountContactController_Test{

    static testMethod void unitTest(){

        AccountContactController Acc = new AccountContactController();
        Account ac = new Account();
        ac.name = 'test';
        // set the acc variable of controller
        Acc.acc = ac;
        <del>insert acc; </del> // no need to make an insert call

        test.startTest();    
        Acc.save();
        test.stopTest();

        // finally test the behavior of the class by assertion
        Contact[] contacts = [SELECT lastname, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE 
        AccountId =: ac.id];
        for (Contact con: contacts) System.assertEquals(con.AccountId, ac.id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code for your test class hope it will help you

```
@isTest
private class AccountContactController_Test{

    static testMethod void unitTest(){

        AccountContactController   Acc = new AccountContactController  ();
        Account ac = new Account();
        ac.name = 'test';
        List<contact> conlist = new List<Contact>();
        contact con = new contact();
        con.lastname='TestCon';
        conlist.add(con);
        Test.startTest();
        Acc.acc = ac;
        Acc.cont =conlist;
        Acc.save();
        Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

Comment: Begging for upvotes/marking as best answer is considered rude here, please don't do it. Beyond that, this answer is what is called a "code dump". It contains code, with no explanation. Code dumps are not good answers because they tend to generate a string of comments like "It didn't work" and "try `<other code>` instead" that go back and forth. A good answer will explain _what_ the problem OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question) was having, _what_ your solution does differently, and _how_ your solution resolves or avoids the issue.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that the OP isn't going to be the only one who looks at this. Other people with similar problems are going to look here for answers to their own problems. Their problems are going to be slightly different than the one OP is having. A good answer will be able to help people with slightly different problems as well. That's why I think explanation is important. If you explain what the issue was, others can more easily identify it in their own code. If you explain how to resolve/work around it, others can more easily apply it to their own code.